# Getting the fileName from HttpRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Basically my application needs to be able to handle large file uploads and for that I looked into the [File uploads docs by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Here they mention large file uploads with streaming, which sounded nice so I copied the code from the docs. However, my problem is that I cannot get the original uploaded file props (FileName, Length etc...) from the HttpRequest.

I have already tried accessing `request.Form.Files`, but that way I get an exception: `IOException: Unexpected end of Stream, the content may have already been read by another component.` Since I try to access the request afterwards again.

What's the best way to get the FileName + Length after the upload has completed (with streaming of course)?

### Edit:

The controller's code currently looks like this:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FileController : Controller
{
    private FileManagerDbContext _context;
    public FileController(FileManagerDbContext context) {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost("upload")]
    [DisableFormValueModelBinding]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload()
    {
        using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create("myfile.temp"))
        {
            await Request.StreamFile(stream);
        }
        var fileToSave = new File();
        fileToSave.FileName = null;
        fileToSave.FileSize = 0;
        fileToSave.UploadDate = new DateTime();
        _context.Files.Add(fileToSave);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        
        return Ok(fileToSave);
    }

}
```

After the file upload is complete, I want to persist some minimal metadata to my database about the uploaded file. But I cannot get the necessary properties.

Comment: Why you are not following the example you have posted. You can get file object in IFormFile interface.

Comment: That only works in the case of smaller files. When large files are being uploaded and you want to upload them using streaming, you have to use the HttpRequest, and not get the request using the IForm interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewind inside of your controller as well if you wish:

```
if (request?.ContentLength != null)
{
    request.EnableRewind();

    request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        body = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //Do your thing with the body content
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will probably use this method instead of generally enabling request rewinding!

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurred if your don't add this attribute on top of your controller action method. It is use to disable the form value model binding here to take control of handling 
potentially large files.

> [DisableFormValueModelBinding]

Comment: Hm...the attribute is already added to the controller. I'll edit the question with the controller's code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so a workaround I found is to enable HttpRequest rewinding. For this I needed to add this piece of code to `Startup.cs`:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
    context.Request.EnableRewind();
    await next();
});
```

This way the UnexpectedEndOfStream exception will not be thrown since, the stream can be rewinded.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the data using the access control file, taking into account that the file has a public URL.

```
            var webRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

            using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                var file_size = webResponse.Headers.Get("Content-Length");
                var file_name = webResponse.ResponseUri.Segments.Last();
            }
```